# How to create a zipfile and write it to multiple directories/folders?

Tags: python, directory, python-zipfile

I have a single .txt file that I want to compress into a zipfile and write into multiple directories.

This function creates a list of directories that I want to read the zipped .txt file:

```
dir_path = 'N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021'
directories_list = retrieve_file_paths(dir_path)
directories_list
```

This is the output:

```
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_ICF_2021
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_IP_2021
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_OP_2021
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_PHYS_2021
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_NF_2021
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_CLNC_2021
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_IMD_2021
N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/2021\Alabama\AL_PRTF_2021
```

NOTE: I want the zipfile placed into the last folder (ex. AL_ICF_2021)

This is the code with the path to the .txt file and my attempt to compress it and write it to the directories list.

```
# Assign the name of the directory to zip
zipfile_name = 'N:/Project/50813_Medicaid_UPL_DSH/NJ1/Data Files from CMS/UPL/Guidance_Document_Extract/_ticket5250_sandbox/guidancedocnotes.txt'
          
# Compress .txt into a zipfile
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('guidancedocnotes.zip', 'w')
zip_file.write(zipfile_name, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    
for folder in folder_list:
    complete_name = os.path.join(zip_file, folder_list)
    print(complete_name)
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-57432b3f2938> in <module>
     24 # Call the main function
     25 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 26     main()

<ipython-input-37-57432b3f2938> in main()
     18 
     19     for folder in folder_list:
---> 20         complete_name = os.path.join(zip_file, folder_list)
     21         print(complete_name)
     22 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py in join(path, *paths)
     74 # Join two (or more) paths.
     75 def join(path, *paths):
---> 76     path = os.fspath(path)
     77     if isinstance(path, bytes):
     78         sep = b'\\'

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ZipFile
```

I basically want to place a separate zipfile called guidancedocsnote.zip into each one of the directories listed above. What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your actual issue is. Looks like you are 90% of the way.
I am not familiar with 'os.path.join' but assuming it is producing a fully qualified path, then you just need to copy and paste the zip file into that location instead of printing the path name.

Might need to provide a bit more information here.

Comment: I attached the error message if that helps

Comment: This line: "complete_name = os.path.join(zip_file, folder_list)"

Should be: "complete_name = os.path.join(zip_file, folder)"

You need to remeber that 'folder' is the individual path, whereas 'folder_list' is the entire list. As you are in a for loop, you should use 'folder'.

Comment: The answer provided by [Mitchell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69186936/9222482) is probably a good place to start. The issue is that you are printing and not saving the file in the folder locations. I am guessing you were doing this to debug and check the folder path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.join` takes in the src and target directory and returns a path. At the moment you are passing in the zipfile object instead of a string. `os.path.join` will not save anything, instead it will return a path to which you could save something.

Your question is not entirely clear, but I think this it what you want

```
# Compress .txt into a zipfile
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('guidancedocnotes.zip', 'w')

for folder in folder_list:
   save_path = os.path.join(folder, zipfile_name)
   zip_file.write(save_path, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: I tried this, and I'm not seeing the zipfile written and saved to the proper folder.